# using metatags gem - need to create different tags for each category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-tags

I'm using the metatags gem - https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags

When it's just adding metatags to the categories pages I can do this and it works:

```
  def show

    @page_title = 'x'
    @page_description = 'x'
    @page_keywords = 'x'


    if params[:city_id]
      @city = City.friendly.find(params[:city_id])
      @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @suppliers = Supplier.for_city_and_category(@city, @category)
                            .order_by_rating.includes(:reviews)
      @review_count = 0
      @suppliers.each { |supplier| @review_count += supplier.reviews.visible.count }
    else
      @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @suppliers = @category.suppliers.order_by_rating.includes(:reviews)
      @review_count = 0
      @suppliers.each { |supplier| @review_count += supplier.reviews.visible.count }

      render 'categories/show_all'
    end
  end
```

However, there are different categories, and I'd like to use different metatags depending on the category. I've tried:

```
  def show

    if Category.name == 'Cars'
      @page_title = 'x'
      @page_description = 'x'
      @page_keywords = 'x'
    end

    if params[:city_id]
      @city = City.friendly.find(params[:city_id])
      @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @suppliers = Supplier.for_city_and_category(@city, @category)
                            .order_by_rating.includes(:reviews)
      @review_count = 0
      @suppliers.each { |supplier| @review_count += supplier.reviews.visible.count }
    else
      @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @suppliers = @category.suppliers.order_by_rating.includes(:reviews)
      @review_count = 0
      @suppliers.each { |supplier| @review_count += supplier.reviews.visible.count }

      render 'categories/show_all'
    end
  end
```

...but it isn't right. I'm not sure how to correctly allocate metatags to individual categories....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Show**

I think you've got your `show` action confused:

```
def show

    if Category.name == 'Cars'
```

This will *never* yield the result you want, as the class `Category` has no instantiated state. Only when you have an `instance` of the `class` will you be able to call the `.name` method:

```
def show
   @category = Category.find params[:id]

   if @category.name == "cars"
      ...
   end
end
```

--

**Meta**

I would do this:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
Class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   after_action :set_tags

   def show
      @category = Category.find params[:id]
      @page_title = @category.name
   end

   private

   def set_tags
      set_title_tag @page_title
   end
end
```

If you wanted to manually set the tags depending on what was returned from the `db`, you could do this:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
Class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @category = Category.find params[:id]
      case @category
         when "car"
            @page_title = "x"
         when "not car"
            @page_title = "y"
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: ok thanks, just working through this and it makes sense. But cars is the category name so I think I need to be specific about category.name somewhere?

Comment: got it thanks, it's just what you said but with @category.name